# Rails optimistic locking update within a loop appears to work until I check from outside of the loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimistic-locking

I'm using optimistic locking on a Rails model. Inside of a loop, I update and save this model (or, rather, many instances of this model).

From inside the loop, I output the "before" and "after" values, and the field appears to be updated correctly. But afterward, when I find the models by ID, I see that the field is not updated. Can anyone spot my error?

```
class Usage::LeadDistributionWeight < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :agent_id, :tag_value_id, :weight, :premium_limit, :countdown, :lock_version, :tag_value

  def increment_countdown!
    self.countdown = self.countdown + self.weight
    save
  rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
    attempts_to_crement_countdown ||= 0
    attempts_to_crement_countdown += 1
    self.increment_countdown! unless attempts_to_crement_countdown > 5
    false
  end

  def self.increment_countdowns parent_id, lead_type_id
    if lead_type_id.present?
      joins(:agent)
      .where("#{reflect_on_association(:agent).table_name}.parent_id = ?", parent_id)
      .where(tag_value_id:lead_type_id)
      .all(readonly:false).each { |weight|
        prev = weight.countdown
        if weight.increment_countdown!
          puts "#{prev} differs from #{weight.countdown}"
        else
          puts "no difference!"
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```